# using multiple sub select query in Hive SQL

Tags: hive

I have the following query in Hive and since Hive doesn't allow more than 1 sub select, I am not sure how to work this out. I looked at existing postings but had nothing that came close to this. I have additional  subselects in this query for more joins. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
    select * from table_a a inner join table_b on a.id = b.id)
     where a.timestamp in (select max(c.timestamp) from table_a c 
                        where c.id = a.id)
      and b.timestamp in (select max(d.timestamp) from table_b dateofbirth  
                         where d.id = b.id);
```